# Append Multiple input file upload upon browse

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to append multiple files when the browse button is clicked but what happen is when I clicked the browse button and select multiple files again, the browsed file get reset(disappear) or get replaced with the new multiple browsed files.
I am doing something similar to http://jsfiddle.net/aHrTd/4/ but instead of single file at a time, I would like to do multiple files at a time

```
<input id="file-upload-plans" type="file" class="file" multiple="multiple" name="floorplans[]" data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="false" data-show-remove="true" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" data-browse-class="btn btn-default">
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this http://jsfiddle.net/aHrTd/67/ could help you

**HTML**

```
<form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onchange="addField();">
<label for="file">Soubor:</label>
<input type="file" name="files[]" class="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Odeslat" value="Odeslat soubor" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.file', function(){
      var e = $(this);
      if(e.val()){
        e.clone().insertAfter(e);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo and u can see outputs there.

```js
$("#file").change(function() {
    var result = $(this)[0].files;
    for(var x = 0;x< result.length;x++){
       var file = result[x];
       // here are the files
        $("#output").append("<p>" + file.name + " (TYPE: " + file.type + ", SIZE: " + file.size + ")</p>");  
    }
    
});
```

```css
p{
  background-color: cyan;
  font-family: open sans;
  max-width: 350px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"  multiple="multiple"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: it works but only the last browse files get uploaded

Comment: @JeVic What do you mean by last browse files? this is what it suppose to do, can u explain more?

Comment: for example you browse 3 files then you browse another 4 files total of 7 files, the first 3 files don't get uploaded but the 4 files get uploaded

Comment: @JeVic With just input files u can't achieve this, for getting more control about your files i recommend u to use this jquery library which handles file uploading process great and u can interact with uploader.  https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but you probably could save the added files with javascript. A few examples here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList